# Ошибка KeyError в функции drop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df.columns
>>> Index(['RowNumber', 'CustomerId', 'Surname', 'CreditScore', 'Geography',
       'Gender', 'Age', 'Tenure', 'Balance', 'NumOfProducts', 'HasCrCard',
       'IsActiveMember', 'EstimatedSalary', 'Exited'],
      dtype='object')

df = df.drop(['RowNumber', 'CustomerId', 'Surname', 'CreditScore'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df>>>KeyError: "['RowNumber' 'CustomerId' 'Surname' 'CreditScore'] not found in axis"
```

Comment: можете привести в вопросе __воспроизводимый__ пример данных?

Comment: вот ссылка на датасет: https://www.kaggle.com/shubh0799/churn-modelling

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

если вы используете параметр `inplace=True`, то замена происходит в самом фрейме и функция возвращает `None`:

```
In [96]: df = pd.read_csv(r"/tmp/Churn_Modelling.csv")

In [97]: df.columns
Out[97]: 
Index(['RowNumber', 'CustomerId', 'Surname', 'CreditScore', 'Geography',
       'Gender', 'Age', 'Tenure', 'Balance', 'NumOfProducts', 'HasCrCard',
       'IsActiveMember', 'EstimatedSalary', 'Exited'],
      dtype='object')

In [98]: df.drop(['RowNumber', 'CustomerId', 'Surname', 'CreditScore'], axis=1, inplace=True)

In [99]: df.columns
Out[99]: 
Index(['Geography', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Tenure', 'Balance', 'NumOfProducts',
       'HasCrCard', 'IsActiveMember', 'EstimatedSalary', 'Exited'],
      dtype='object')
```

поэтому надо делать либо так:

```
df.drop(['RowNumber', 'CustomerId', 'Surname', 'CreditScore'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

либо так:

```
df = df.drop(['RowNumber', 'CustomerId', 'Surname', 'CreditScore'], axis=1)
```

лично я предпочитаю более явный стиль:

```
df = df.drop(columns=['RowNumber', 'CustomerId', 'Surname', 'CreditScore'])
```

Comment: Так ведь я же вроде так и делаю? По вашему первому варианту

Comment: все три ваших варианта дают ту же самую ошибку

Comment: @nich123, значит вы изменили фрейм между тем как прочитали его и перед тем как удалять столбцы - чудес не бывает. Попробуйте перечитать CSV файл в фрейм и __следующей__ командой запустить `df = df.drop(columns=['RowNumber', 'CustomerId', 'Surname', 'CreditScore'])`

Comment: нет ничего не менял, дело в том, что и в других датасетах та же проблема присутствует, попробую перегрузить анаконду